# Refactoring UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, getderivedstatefromprops

I have an `IFrameComponent` component, inspired by [this post](https://medium.com/@ebakhtarov/handling-of-iframes-in-react-f038be46ac24).

It looks basically like this :

```
class IFrameComponent extends React.Component {
    shouldComponentUpdate() {
        return false;
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if(this.props.content !== nextProps.content) {
            const html = getHTMLFromContent();
            const fdoc = this.iFrame.contentDocument;
            fdoc.write(html);
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (<iframe sandbox="..." ref={f => this.iFrame = f} />);
    }
}
```

Now that `componentWillReceiveProps` is considered unsafe, I'm trying to get rid of it.

[The ways React advices to refactor componentWillReceiveProps](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html) are basically either to use `static getDerivedStateFromProps` or `componentDidUpdate`

Sadly, `componentDidUpdate` will never get called, because `shouldComponentUpdate` returns false (and I think this is fine ?) and I wouldn't be able to access this.iFrame reference in the static method `getDerivedStateFromProps`.

How would one refactor this code ?

Answer (score 1):

I think, One possible way is:

```
let iFrameRefs = {}

class IFrameComponent extends React.Component {
    static getDerivedStateFromProps (props) {
        if (iFrameRefs[props.id]) {
            const html = getHTMLFromContent();
            const fdoc = iFrameRefs[props.id].contentDocument;
            fdoc.write(html);
        }
        return null
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate() {
        return false;
    }

    render() {
        return (<iframe sandbox="..." ref={f => iFrameRefs[this.props.id] = f} />);
    }
}
```

Now from Parent Component pass unique id to each component. You can also manage id in `IFrameComponent`.

```
<IFrameComponent id='1' />
<IFrameComponent id='2' />
```

Comment: Indeed, this works, although I don't feel very comfortable putting my refs outside of my object. Side note : in order to help future readers, could you add `if(iFrame && (props.content !== state.content))` and `return {content: props.content}` in `getDerivedStateFromProps`, in order to reflect the former `if(this.props.content !== nextProps.content)` ?

Comment: Sorry but I had to unaccept your answer because it has a major flaw : If the component is rendered multiple times by the parent, only one iFrame will be filled in by all the components :(

Comment: I realize my comment was not precise at all. What I meant was : If the parent component renders multiple instances of IFrameComponent, then all of these components will share the same IFrame reference.

Comment: yeah I thought of that solution too, it will work but does not feel right at all, does it ?